# add prefix to every line when print to output with tee

Tags: bash, shell

I have command like this

```
command | tee /dev/tty | grep ...
```

that say prints

```
hello
world
```

I would like to change this so every line from the command output to be prefixed, in the output or it to looks, say:

```
# hello
# world
```

Comment: yes, I have idea how to prefix it. The question is how to do this in the scope of tee

Comment: that's not tee's job. it just splits its input into two output streams. you'd need `command | tee | awk | grep` or `awk | tee` if you need both streams to have the modified text.

Comment: this will prefix for the grep processing or for both. Only the output to be prefixed, not the pipe for processing

Comment: then `tee | awk`. by the time awk kicks in, the original data's already been written to disk. awk can't do anything about that data stream, it'll only see the stuff `tee` wrote to stdout.

Comment: what do you mean to disk - there is no disk involved here

Comment: tee takes a single input stream and out puts it to two places. a file you designate (/dev/tty in this case), and stdout. /dev/tty IS a file, that just happens to represent your terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bash [Process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) might help

```
printf 'hello\nworld\n' | tee >(awk '{print "#"$0}' > /dev/tty) | grep hello
hello
#hello
#world
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. thanks 3 more minutes and I will select it as answer